# Busca por proximidade

Tags: php, algoritmo-de-busca, geolocalização

Estou em busca de tutoriais que me auxiliem a implementar uma busca por proximidade (como nesse link:https://www.palfinger.com/pt-BR/bra/representantes-de-vendas/localizador-de-representante). Percebam que além da sua localização ele utiliza outros filtros (select e checkbox). Bom, meu forte é front-end, mas ja comecei a aprender PHP e mySQL.

Como eu chego a esse resultado? Que tipo de tutoriais eu devo buscar? Quais são as linguagens usadas? Tudo que vcs puderem me esclarecer quanto a isso seria ótimo.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Olha o site do http://www.banco24horas.com.br/para-voce/busca-banco24-horas

Comment: aqui tem a API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Answer (score 1):

No PHP é basicamente isso:

```
   public function getGeocodeAddress($lat, $long)
        {
            $url = "https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" . $lat . "," . $long . "&sensor=true";

            $data = @file_get_contents($url);
            $jsondata = json_decode($data, true);
            if (is_array($jsondata) && $jsondata['status'] == "OK") {
                $addressComponents = $jsondata['results'];
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($addressComponents); $i++) {
                    for ($j = 0; $j < count($addressComponents[$i]['address_components']); $j++) {
                        $typeName = $addressComponents[$i]['address_components'][$j]['types'][0];
                        if ('locality' == $typeName) {
                            return strtolower($addressComponents[$i]['address_components'][$j]['long_name']);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Olha aqui a saída: **http://ideone.com/rePEIv**